# How to Get Crawl content in Crawljax

Tags: java, web-crawler

I have crawl Dynamic webpage using Crawljax. i can able to get crawl current id, status and dom. but i can't get the Website content.. Any one help me??

```
CrawljaxConfigurationBuilder builder =
            CrawljaxConfiguration.builderFor("http://demo.crawljax.com/");
    builder.addPlugin(new OnNewStatePlugin() {



        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Our example plugin";
        }

                @Override
                public void onNewState(CrawlerContext cc, StateVertex sv) {

                    LOG.info("Found a new dom! Here it is:\n{}", cc.getBrowser().getStrippedDom());
                       String name = cc.getCurrentState().getName();
String url = cc.getBrowser().getCurrentUrl();
System.out.println(cc.getCurrentState().getDom());
System.out.println("New State: " + name + "; url: " + url);
                }
    });
    CrawljaxRunner crawljax = new CrawljaxRunner(builder.build());
    crawljax.call();
```

How to get dynamic/java script Webpage content..

Comment: [Related question by same user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085211/any-possibility-to-crawl-open-web-browser-data-using-aperture)

Comment: If you can get the DOM, you can get the content, right? It's the same thing.

Comment: No. i can't get the content. it displayed null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can able to get website source code
cc.getBrowser().getStrippedDom()); or cc.getCurrentState().getDocument();
This coding are Return Source code (css/java script file)..

Not possible.Because its testing tool.This tool only check Text are available, assign temp data to Fields.

Answer (score -1):

To get the website content, use the following function:

```
cc.getCurrentState().getDom()
```

This function does **not** return a DOM node, but actually returns the page's HTML text instead. This is the right function to use if you want the page content, but it sounds like it returns a DOM node, so the name `getDom` is a misnomer. To get a DOM node instead, use:

```
cc.getCurrentState().getDocument()
```

which returns the `Document` DOM node.

<del>You can retrieve the page content with:</del>

<del>cc.getCurrentState().getDocument().getTextContent()</del>

(**EDIT**: This won't work -- `getTextContent` always [returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14279558/1422127) when called on Documents.)

Comment: Can you check it.. it's displayed Null Value

Comment: then.How can get text value?